R random numbers almost the same but not identical
Running the same version of R, one on a Linux R server and one on AWS, the RNG is almost the same, but not always identical.  Out of 1 million samples from the uniform, gamma, and Normal distributions respectively:

runif() produces identical results.
rgamma() produces 7 small differences; otherwise identical results.
rnorm() also produces 7 small differences; otherwise identical results.

By small differences, I mean something like 1.4510448921274106 vs 1.4510448921274115.
What would be causing these differences? If a floating point issue, why only some distributions? If an OS/library/software issue, why only different on rare occasions?

From the set.seed help page: "Do not rely on randomness of low-order bits from RNGs. Most of the supplied uniform generators return 32-bit integer values that are converted to doubles, "

Yeah, that doesn't explain why they are converted inconsistently though. I could understand if all 1M were out by 5e-16.

Different CPUs (or even the same CPU with different settings) may have slight variations in precision handling for doubles.

High-energy subatomic particles from solar storms flipping bits in RAM? ;-)

@IRTFM True, but again, that does not explain the inconsistency.  Why would that not affect uniform random variates? And why only very infrequently if precision handling differs? Do you have any evidence you could point me to so I can investigate further?

It's those dang sophons again!

runif() is not implemented in floating point; it's doing integer arithmetic internally (at least for the default Mersenne-Twister algorithm, and probably for all the available algorithms). You can see the code for Mersenne Twister here; in particular, you can see that the result is only converted to double-precision floating point at the very end (line 725). So it is not subject to cross-platform/cross-compiler floating-point artifacts.
As for "why [are the others] only different on rare occasions?"; I assume that the rgamma() and rnorm() implementations are relatively numerically stable, so that the possibilities for differential floating-point/roundoff error are rare — especially if the differences have to do only with the use of 80-bit registers for intermediate computations (vs the default 64-bit precision).

Thank you for the explanation; that does make sense. Actually, wouldn't runif() just be tied to the long list of stored pseudo random numbers? i.e. calling runit() just regurgitates the next PRN in the list, based on the seed? The R help file doesn't elaborate how runif() works.

There's not a "list of stored pseudo random numbers"; there's a deterministic algorithm that produces the next deviate, based on the current state of the generator (and updates the generator). See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister  (?runif points you to ?RNG, which does give more information on the algorithms ...)

Fair enough. So its not a stored list, but such a list could be generated using the deterministic algorithm. I recall a colleague who actually found the RNG repeating the same numbers in a lengthy simulation which required manual intervention to restore "randomness" (hence my perception of such a list).

The period of the Mersenne-Twister PRNG itself is extremely large (2^19937 - 1, approximately 1e6001). It may be that your colleague was doing something with the deviates that relied on the low-order bits (as warned by @IRTFM in comments above)?

This is going back about 10 years, and for full disclosure, while she used R, this problem might not have been R - perhaps the software she experienced this in was using a different method or in fact did use a stored list. (I think it might have been PyMC).

Might be affected by FPU settings as well, I put it into answer below

Besides for seed choice, your issue might lies in the choice of the Pseudo-random Number Generator (PRNG) that your R environment is using.
R usually implements the Mersenne Twister by default for generating random numbers which are then scaled to a range between 0 and 1 - thus simulating uniform random variables. The other distributions can then be simulated via the inverse probability transform.
For a easier understanding of how PRNGs work- check out this Kahn Academy video.
Additionally you can also check out the R documentation on this topic:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Random
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Random.user

If you want to look at implementing different PRNGs to see what happens "under the hood" with R. I am in the process of developing an R package that allows users to implement different PRNGs via functions. Check it out here.


Very interesting. We did try different kind and normal.kind parameters of set.seed, but same result. Also, I'm pretty sure rgamma uses an accept-reject algorithm based on the 1974 Ahrens and Dieter paper rather than inverse probability function as its more efficient. This source contains R code for how some univariate distributions RNG is done: https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1180&context=jmasm

Indeed, I think none of the base-R non-uniform deviate generators use inverse probability transform (with the possible exception of exponential, where the IPT is very easy).

Following prof. @BenBolker excellent answer, I could add that one could check and see if FPU control word(s) are the same. This would be platform specific, but some are partially abstracted in R, in .Machine, see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html for details.
E.g. you could check or set .Machine$double.rounding or .Machine$double.guard, and those settings might change your results.
Same goes for .Machine$longdouble values.
